# Shallow routes with path_prefix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Recently I changed a few nested resources in one of my applications to use shallow routing. It's working great and I've been able to simplify my views and controllers.

However, I've been using a path_prefix before:

```
map.with_options :path_prefix => "blog" do |blog|
  blog.resources :posts do |posts|
    posts.resources :comments
  end
end
```

Notice, that all routes are prefixed with "/blog" as expected.

```
# $ rake routes
#             posts GET    /blog/posts(.:format)                            {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"index"}
#                   POST   /blog/posts(.:format)                            {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"create"}
#          new_post GET    /blog/posts/new(.:format)                        {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"new"}
#         edit_post GET    /blog/posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"edit"}
#              post GET    /blog/posts/:id(.:format)                        {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"show"}
#                   PUT    /blog/posts/:id(.:format)                        {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"update"}
#                   DELETE /blog/posts/:id(.:format)                        {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"destroy"}
#     post_comments GET    /blog/posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"index"}
#                   POST   /blog/posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"create"}
#  new_post_comment GET    /blog/posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)      {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"new"}
# edit_post_comment GET    /blog/posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"edit"}
#      post_comment GET    /blog/posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"show"}
#                   PUT    /blog/posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"update"}
#                   DELETE /blog/posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"destroy"}
```

The new routing configuration looks like this:

```
map.with_options :path_prefix => "blog", :shallow => true do |blog|
  blog.resources :posts do |posts|
    posts.resources :comments
  end
end
```

Now, the "/blog" prefix is missing in some of my routes.

```
# $ rake routes
#            posts GET    /blog/posts(.:format)                  {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"index"}
#                  POST   /blog/posts(.:format)                  {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"create"}
#         new_post GET    /blog/posts/new(.:format)              {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"new"}
#        edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)              {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"edit"}
#             post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                   {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"show"}
#                  PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                   {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"update"}
#                  DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                   {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"destroy"}
#    post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)     {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"index"}
#                  POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)     {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"create"}
# new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format) {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"new"}
#     edit_comment GET    /comments/:id/edit(.:format)           {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"edit"}
#          comment GET    /comments/:id(.:format)                {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"show"}
#                  PUT    /comments/:id(.:format)                {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"update"}
#                  DELETE /comments/:id(.:format)                {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"destroy"}
```

I'm looking for a solution to get the prefixes back for all routes. I know that it's working with namespaces (`map.namespace :blog do`), but I want to prevent refactoring all my controllers/views/tests to actually use namespaces.

All code samples are tested with Rails version 2.3.2 and Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: Hi Cristoph, if my answer wasn't enough I may be able to help more but would you please clarify the end result you're looking for and any criteria you have for an ideal solution?  What was the original testing issue you're trying to solve by making this change?

Comment: Actually it's quite simple: I'm trying to create shallow routes with a *static* path prefix such as "/blog" in my example.

Comment: Is Raimonds's answer doing what you need?  Or if not, what are the specific routes you're looking for?

Comment: Yeah, it's doing what i want.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I updated my answer as a result.

Comment: i'm sorry! both answers are basically equivalent. i just picked one randomly ;)

Comment: Adam just picked my proposed solution and pasted it with small modification into his answer :)

Comment: Raimonds I did see Christoph mention that your answer was helpful.  I felt it was very close to ideal but was able to improve it slightly by making it more concise, in the interest of providing a helpful answer.  I apologize if any offense was taken; it was not intended.  Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the documentation seems to indicate this exact behavior is by design:

> :shallow - If true, paths for nested resources which reference a specific member (ie. those with an :id parameter) will not use the parent path prefix or name prefix.

(from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html#M000501)

Since using the :shallow option will cause your :path_prefix to be ignored in some cases, if you must always have this prefix you should consider removing the :shallow option.  Here's an alternate solution that appears to do what you need:

```
map.with_options :path_prefix => "blog" do |blog|
  blog.resources :posts do |posts|
    posts.resources :comments, :only => [:index, :create, :new]
  end
  blog.resources :comments, :except => [:index, :create, :new]
end
```

Resulting in these routes:

```
#             posts GET    /blog/posts                               {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"index"}
#                   POST   /blog/posts                               {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"create"}
#          new_post GET    /blog/posts/new                           {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"new"}
#         edit_post GET    /blog/posts/:id/edit                      {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"edit"}
#              post GET    /blog/posts/:id                           {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"show"}
#                   PUT    /blog/posts/:id                           {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"update"}
#                   DELETE /blog/posts/:id                           {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"destroy"}
#     post_comments GET    /blog/posts/:post_id/comments             {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"index"}
#                   POST   /blog/posts/:post_id/comments             {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"create"}
#  new_post_comment GET    /blog/posts/:post_id/comments/new         {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"new"}
#      edit_comment GET    /blog/comments/:id/edit                   {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"edit"}
#           comment GET    /blog/comments/:id                        {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"show"}
#                   PUT    /blog/comments/:id                        {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"update"}
#                   DELETE /blog/comments/:id                        {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"destroy"}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It seemed a litlle bit strange that you copied and pasted my proposed solution to your answer. I guess you wanted these 100 bonus points so much that tried to do everything to earn them :)

Comment: Raimonds I did see Christoph mention that your answer was helpful.  I felt it was very close to ideal but was able to improve it slightly by making it more concise, in the interest of providing a helpful answer.  I apologize if any offense was taken; it was not intended.  Thank you for helping.

Comment: OK, everything is fine :) I also agree that moving the last line inside map.with_options block was good in terms of readability.

Answer (score 5):

Probably the easiest solution would not be to use :shallow option but create the same routes with additional resource definition:

```
map.with_options :path_prefix => "blog" do |blog|
  blog.resources :posts do |posts|
    posts.resources :comments, :only => [:index, :create, :new]
  end
end
map.resources :comments, :path_prefix => "blog",
              :except => [:index, :create, :new]
```

which gives the following routes definitions:

```
# $ rake routes
#            posts GET    /blog/posts(.:format)                       {:action=>"index", :controller=>"posts"}
#                  POST   /blog/posts(.:format)                       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"posts"}
#         new_post GET    /blog/posts/new(.:format)                   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"posts"}
#        edit_post GET    /blog/posts/:id/edit(.:format)              {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts"}
#             post GET    /blog/posts/:id(.:format)                   {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"}
#                  PUT    /blog/posts/:id(.:format)                   {:action=>"update", :controller=>"posts"}
#                  DELETE /blog/posts/:id(.:format)                   {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"posts"}
#    post_comments GET    /blog/posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)     {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments"}
#                  POST   /blog/posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"comments"}
# new_post_comment GET    /blog/posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format) {:action=>"new", :controller=>"comments"}
#     edit_comment GET    /blog/comments/:id/edit(.:format)           {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments"}
#          comment GET    /blog/comments/:id(.:format)                {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments"}
#                  PUT    /blog/comments/:id(.:format)                {:action=>"update", :controller=>"comments"}
#                  DELETE /blog/comments/:id(.:format)                {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"comments"}
```